# Filtering out raw data report through basic macro

Tags: excel, vba, variables, filtering

I'm trying to take the elaborate filtering and deleting that I have to do every day when dealing with a raw data report and reduce as much of it as I can down to a single button click.

I believe I have done most of this through a simple recorded macro (seen below) but it will sometimes leave in certain entries for items that I want deleted. Looking at the code I believe this could be down to the fact that as the macro is applying filters the starting rows it looks for when attempting to delete content aren't fixed. So my question is, should I just use Offset values based on the row that currently holds the filter? Or would this not work as well?

The Issues are arising when I'm deleting the Criteria "POR" "<>BGR" and "=Sunrise Earth" I think it is because the select function that follows these commands has a variable row number that might not always be true

```
Sub ProgMisr()
'
' ProgMisr Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("I:I,K:K,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$5761").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>EHD*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>ESD*"
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1412").AutoFilter Field:=2
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1412").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Missing Audio", "Missing Audio/Subs", "Missing Subs"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1412").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=DCBU", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=TLBA"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1412").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="="
    Rows("13:13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1069").AutoFilter Field:=7
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1069").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>*BGR*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("66:66").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1059").AutoFilter Field:=8
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1059").AutoFilter Field:=3
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1059").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="POR"
    Rows("12:12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$809").AutoFilter Field:=7
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$809").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "Missing Subs"
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$133").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "=Missing Audio", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Missing Audio/Subs"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$133").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*Sunrise Earth*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("17:17").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$112").AutoFilter Field:=1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$112").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="ENG"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$112").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "AHPL", "APPL", "CIPO", "DPOL", "IDPL", "SCPO", "TLPO", "WOIT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$55").AutoFilter Field:=3
    Range("B11").Select
End Sub
```

EDIT: New Macro Code

```
Sub ProgMisr()
'
' ProgMisr Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("I:I,K:K,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>EHD*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>ESD*"
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Missing Audio", "Missing Audio/Subs", "Missing Subs"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=DCBU", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=TLBA"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="="
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>*BGR*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$ & LastRow").AutoFilter Field:=8
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$ & LastRow").AutoFilter Field:=3
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$ & LastRow").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="POR"
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$ & LastRow").AutoFilter Field:=7
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$ & LastRow").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "Missing Subs"
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "=Missing Audio", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Missing Audio/Subs"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*Sunrise Earth*", Operator:=xlAnd
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="ENG"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "AHPL", "APPL", "CIPO", "DPOL", "IDPL", "SCPO", "TLPO", "WOIT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
    Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3
    Range("B11").Select
End Sub
```

EDIT 2:

```
Sub ProgMisr()
'
' ProgMisr Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("I:I,K:K,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>EHD*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>ESD*"
    VisibleCell = Range("A7:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Missing Audio", "Missing Audio/Subs", "Missing Subs"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=DCBU", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=TLBA"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="="
    VisibleCell = Range("A7:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>*BGR*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    VisibleCell = Range("A7:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=8
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="POR"
    VisibleCell = Range("A7:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "Missing Subs"
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "=Missing Audio", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Missing Audio/Subs"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*Sunrise Earth*", Operator:=xlAnd
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="ENG"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "AHPL", "APPL", "CIPO", "DPOL", "IDPL", "SCPO", "TLPO", "WOIT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
    Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3
    Range("B11").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The macro is a bit messy so its kind of hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Can you say what data would you like to delete/filtered and were is the data located on the sheet so the macro would make more sense.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That everything worked out well, you should be parameterized to filter the data range and scope of data to be deleted.

Instead of using `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$5761").AutoFilter` or `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1412").AutoFilter` ... you can first calculate the last line of all data, for example `LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row` (before you use first AutoFilter). Now you can replece them something like this:
`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow).AutoFilter` + your parameters for each AutoFilter

After using AutoFilter you match first row of selected data and select all them:

```
Rows("7:7").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Note that after each AutoFilter row number may be different. You can use this to calculate first row:

```
Set VisibleCell = Range("A6:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1)
RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

I hope that will help you to solve the problem.

Edit - insted:

```
Set VisibleCell = Range("A7:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1)
RowsToSelect = VisibleCell.Row
Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

You can use:

```
VisibleCell = Range("A7:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row
Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Ist shorter :)

Comment: I've tried both the long and short way you have suggested but keep hitting an error at the `Set VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row` stage, a "mismatch" error to be precise.

Comment: try this: `VisibleCell = Range("A2:I" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row` in shorter way there is no "set"

Comment: Should I not set it to A7:I? As the filter is being set on Row 6?

Comment: Also I'm getting a "Run-time Error 424 Object Required" on the `RowsToSelect =VisibleCell.Row` line

I'll put my updated macro in my question

Comment: @Chris: little mess after previous modifications :) after delete 'set' and we dont need auxiliary variable `RowsToSelect`, you can remove this line and modify `Rows(RowsToSelect & ":" & RowsToSelect).Select` to `Rows(VisibleCell & ":" & VisibleCell).Select`

Comment: @Chris: yes, if filter is begin on 6 row you can change to A7

Comment: @Chris: one more thing, in serval place you use `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$ & LastRow")` should be `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$" & LastRow)`

Comment: Hey, I made the above amendments but for some reason now when I run it at a certain point it's deleting the contents of rows 1-6 I can't workout why with my limited knowledge. I'll paste the amended code back in the question

Comment: I just noticed I had a couple of A2's left in there. This now seems to work! I'm going to test it extensively on Monday, but as of right now you are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Still didn't quite understand what you are shooting for but do you wanna try the code below and see if it does the trick for you?

I would advise you to make a copy of the sheet before running the code just in case you wanna make some alterations.

```
Sub Delete_Data_Test()

    'array of which data you want to delete
    DaleteArray = Array("EHD", "ESD", "DCBU", "TLBA", "BGR", "POR", "Missing Audio", "Missing Audio/Subs", "Missing Subs", "Sunrise Earth", "AHPL", "APPL", "CIPO", "DPOL", "IDPL", "SCPO", "TLPO", "WOIT")

    'for each individual in the Deleting Array
    For Each Word In DeleteArray

        'find word to delete in column A
        Set findWord = Range("A:A").Find _
                        (what:=(Word), LookIn:=xlValues)
        'find the last row in the Worksheet
        Set findLastrow = Range("A:A").Find _
            ("*", After:=Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

            'while there is a Word on column A that needs deleting
            Do While Not findWord Is Nothing

                'double check the value
                If Cells(findWord.Row, 1).Value = Word Then

                    'delete entire row that contains the word in column A
                    Row(findWord.Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp

                Else
                    'find the next time the word appears
                    Set findtext = Range("F" & findWord.Row & ":F" & findLastrow.Row).Find _
                    (what:=(Word), LookIn:=xlValues)
                End If

            Loop

    Next

End Sub
```

Check it out and see if that's what you need or if something needs re-jigging.

BTW you should have a look at some of [these](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html) to get more familiarised with VBA.

Comment: The problem is I only want to delete certain words under certain circumstances. For instance at the beginning I am deleting any thing that does not start with EHD or ESD. Subsequent to that I am deleting lines that rows DCBU or TLBA but don't contain BUL and then I'm deleting rows that contain DCBU or  TLBA and BUL but don't contain BGR.

Any row that contains Missing Subs is being deleted and any row that has Sunrise Earth in column A is being deleted, but then it gets complicated again with only lines that contain ENG and those 4 letter codes can be deleted.

Comment: @Chris, could you add a screenshot of what the worksheet and your data look like to your question? I was under the impression that you wanted to delete the full set of deletable data in one go, but the subs can be separated into 2 or 3 or a userform so you'd only run the deletion of certain set of data at a time.